# Удалил безвозвратно файлы с рабочего стола (OneDrive облако)

Tags: windows, файлы

Возникла самая страшная проблема каждого человека или подростка. Решил я почистить компьютер, так как заметил, что диск "C" забит. Зашёл в приложение WizTree. Сканировал, увидел, где больше всего занято, стал удалять файлы. И случайно удалил папку OneDrive, в которой была папка Рабочего Стола. Удалилось всё нужное. В особенности, папка со всеми фотографиями моей мамы, где было очень много фотографий, где-то ГБ 10 точно.

Обшарпал весь интернет, как восстановить удалённые файлы. Ничего не помогает, Recuva вообще ничего не видит. Что вообще можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 2):

> Если вы случайно удалили файл или папку в OneDrive, вы сможете
> восстановить их позже из OneDrive корзины.

[knock ^^](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-onedrive-949ada80-0026-4db3-a953-c99083e6a84f)